# Binding Dropdownlist using jquery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I am try to bind the dropdowmlist using jquery. But is showing some error.

Code:

```
                     $.ajax({
                      type: "POST",
                      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                      data: "{product: '" + product + "'}",
                      url: "Search.aspx/FetchCategory",
                      dataType: "json",
                      success: function(data) {
                      $.each(data.d, function() {
                              $("#ddlCategory").append($("<option></option>").val(this['ID']).html(this['Category']));
                          });
                      }
                  });
```

values in the data:
            [{"Category":"All","ID":"%"},"Category":"Action,"ID":"4"},"Category":"Race,"ID":"5"},"Category":"Sports,"ID":"6"}]

Error:

$("#ddlCategory").append($("").val(this['ID']).html(this['Category']));
   Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method

Geetha

Comment: JavaScript is case-sensitive; the field in your data is 'Category' while your attempting to access 'category'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Geetha:
It looks like data.d is returning an array which contains objects?

Try implementing success like this:

```
success: function(data) {
    $.each(data.d[0], function(key,value) {
     $("#ddlCategory").append($("<option></option>").val(key).html(value));
    });
}
```

Comment: I also want to insert id in all the options.So how can i do that???
<option id="opt1" value="opt1">option1</option>

Comment: You can modify the element builder `"<option></option>"` to contain as much or as little as you want.  For example, you could do `'<option id="'+key+'"></option>'` or just  `"<option />"`.  Notice how when adding attributes manually, I've used double quotes for the attributes and single quotes for the string passed to jQuery. I believe double quotes are XHTML standard (? maybe?) and this simplified escaping the quotes.